# Last tableview cell makes all cells expand - swift

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, cell, expand

I am creating a `UITableViewCell` that expands the cell when clicked. Essentially everything works, but I have a problem when I click on the last cell. When this happens all cells expand to `200` (height). Below is my code. I would appreciate the help of the community on this issue.

```
var selectedIndexPath : NSIndexPath?

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
  return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
  return 4
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellID, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! Cell
  cell.titleLabel.text = "Test Title"
  return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
  let previousIndexPath = selectedIndexPath
  if indexPath == selectedIndexPath {
    selectedIndexPath = nil
  } else {
    selectedIndexPath = indexPath
  }

  var indexPaths : Array<NSIndexPath> = []
  if let previous = previousIndexPath {
    indexPaths += [previous]
  }
  if let current = selectedIndexPath {
    indexPaths += [current]
  }
  if indexPaths.count > 0 {
    tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
  }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
  (cell as! Cell).watchFrameChanges()
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplayingCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
  (cell as! Cell).ignoreFrameChanges()
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
  super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
  for cell in tableView.visibleCells as! [Cell] {
    cell.ignoreFrameChanges()
  }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
  if indexPath == selectedIndexPath {
    return Cell.expandedHeight
  } else {
    return Cell.defaultHeight
  }
}
```

As for the tableview ell class, the code is:

```
var isObserving = false;    
@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
class var expandedHeight: CGFloat { get { return 200 } }
class var defaultHeight: CGFloat  { get { return 40  } }

func checkHeight() {
  titleLabel.hidden = (frame.size.height < Cell.expandedHeight)
}

func watchFrameChanges() {
  if !isObserving {
    addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "frame", options: [NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, NSKeyValueObservingOptions.Initial], context: nil)
    isObserving = true;
  }
}

func ignoreFrameChanges() {
  if isObserving {
    removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "frame")
    isObserving = false;
  }
}

override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
  if keyPath == "frame" {
    checkHeight()
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I'd change the comparing of index paths from `==` to `func compare(_ otherObject: NSIndexPath) -> NSComparisonResult`, more : https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSIndexPath_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSIndexPath/compare:

Comment: I put your code into a test project and it works correctly for all 4 rows